# Switch between languages within the same document

Tags: languages

This might be an odd question.

To my knowledge one have to initialize a language babel in Latex.
But I was wondering if it's possible to make a variable inside overleaf indicating the languages and then some sort of if statement, such that certain files are included if variable var equals Language A another set of files is included if variable var equals languages B and so forth.

Instead of having 20+ different documents, then have them all in the same document and switch between languages?

Comment: Do you mean, like [this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575611/a-mode-to-produce-a-document-in-one-language-or-the-other)

Comment: Similar task indeed. But instead of translating in bites, I would like to include files. I'm not quite sure how to apply it in my case. I will give it a try and return if it does not help me any further.

Comment: I have tried it now, and it works with input files as well as just text. Thank you.