# Multi language text

Tags: languages, programming

I am writing my CV with LaTeX, right now I have the code below that I use to create two commands `\eng{}` and `\ita{}` that allows me to hide text in the language I do not want.

```
%% English %%
\newtoggle{eng}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\iftoggle{eng}{#1}{}}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{cv}}{\jobname}}{
  \toggletrue{eng}
}{
  \togglefalse{eng}
}

%% Italian %%
\newtoggle{ita}
\newcommand{\ita}[1]{\iftoggle{ita}{#1}{}}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{cv-ita}}{\jobname}}{
  \toggletrue{ita}
}{
  \togglefalse{ita}
}
```

These toggles are set depending on a parameters on the command line, if no parameter is passed only the English language is kept, if instead the command line looks like:

```
pdflatex -jobname=cv-ita cv
```

then everything inside the `\eng{}` command is hidden thus leaving only the Italian language.

I would like to improve on this so that if there is no Italian text the English one is used. Unfortunately programming in TeX is quite difficult for me.

Do you have any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

This is how I currently use the commands defined above:

```
\cvsection{ \eng{EDUCATION}
            \ita{FORMAZIONE}}
```

The problem is that if I only have `\eng{EDUCATION}` and I call the compiler with the `ita` flag I get an error because there is no text inside `\cvsection`. Instead of getting the error I would like the command to fallback to the English text.

I think the best idea to accomplish this is to define a new command, something like:

```
\lan{English text}{Italian text}
```

that defaults to English when there is no Italian text.
Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: What do you mean "I would like to improve on this so that if there is no Italian text the English one is used"? Can you show some example code of what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to the site! [Does this help?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575611/a-mode-to-produce-a-document-in-one-language-or-the-other/575613#575613)

Comment: The translator package seems interesting but according to [its documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/translator?lang=en) it _is not intended to be used to automatically translate more than a few words_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the language based on the job name. I called the main file `fabbri.tex` and then called LaTeX via

```bash
pdflatex -jobname=fabbri-ita fabbri
pdflatex -jobname=fabbri-eng fabbri
```

Here is the code; the variable parts are given as “multiple arguments” to `\lc`. Of course the part from `\ExplSyntaxOn` to `\ExplSyntaxOff` may go in a `lcsetup.tex` file that's `\input`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,french,english]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% the main command
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\lc}{m} % language choice
 {
  \fabbri_lc:n { #1 }
 }
% we can change the language mid document
\NewDocumentCommand{\setlclanguage}{m}
 {
  \fabbri_lc_set:n { #1 }
 }

% variables
\str_new:N \l_fabbri_lc_lang_str
\str_new:N \l_fabbri_lc_fallback_str

% internal functions
\cs_new:Nn \fabbri_lc:n
 {
  \str_case:VnF \l_fabbri_lc_lang_str
    { #1 }
    { \str_case:Vn \l_fabbri_lc_fallback_str { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fabbri_lc_set:n
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_fabbri_lc_lang_str { #1 }
  \fabbri_lc:n
   {
    {ita}{\selectlanguage{italian}}
    {fra}{\selectlanguage{french}}
    {eng}{\selectlanguage{english}}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fabbri_lc_set:n { e }


% setup
% set the default language based on \jobname of the form <name>-<lang>
\seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { - } \c_sys_jobname_str
\fabbri_lc_set:e { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }

% set the fallback language
\str_set:Nn \l_fabbri_lc_fallback_str { eng } % choose the fallback language

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{\lc{
  {ita}{Titolo}
  {fra}{Titre}
  {eng}{Title}
}}

\lc{
 {ita}{Questo documento è in italiano}
 {fra}{Ce document est in français}
 {eng}{This document is in English}
}

% French is missing here
\lc{
  {ita}{Testo}
  {eng}{Text}
}

% change the default language
\setlclanguage{fra}

\section{\lc{
  {ita}{Titolo}
  {fra}{Titre}
  {eng}{Title}
}}

\lc{
 {ita}{Questo documento è in italiano}
 {fra}{Ce document est in français}
 {eng}{This document is in English}
}

% French is missing here
\lc{
  {ita}{Testo}
  {eng}{Text}
}

\end{document}
```

Output for `ita`

[image]

Output for `eng`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be working perfectly but I will have study your code because, as of right now, I do not really understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{ita}
\toggletrue{ita}

\newcommand\lan[2]{%
  \ifboolexpe{
    (not togl {ita}) or test{\ifstrempty{#2}}
  }{#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\lan{English}{Italian}

\lan{Only English}{}

\end{document}
```

Note that I did not even define a toggle for the English version, only "Italian or not Italian".

Edit: to account for three languages, as requested in a comment (not really elegant code, but it works):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{ita}
\newtoggle{swe}

\newcommand\lan[3]{%
  \ifboolexpe {test{\ifstrempty{#2}} or not togl{ita}}
    {%
        \ifboolexpe {test{\ifstrempty{#3}} or not togl{swe}}
            {#1}
            {#3}%
    }
    {#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{English:}\par
\lan{English}{Italian}{Swedish}\par
\lan{English}{Italian}{}\par
\lan{English}{}{Swedish}\par
\lan{English}{}{}\par

\textbf{Swedish:}\par
\toggletrue{swe}
\lan{English}{Italian}{Swedish}\par
\lan{English}{Italian}{}\par
\lan{English}{}{Swedish}\par
\lan{English}{}{}\par

\textbf{Italian:}\par
\toggletrue{ita}
\togglefalse{swe}
\lan{English}{Italian}{Swedish}\par
\lan{English}{Italian}{}\par
\lan{English}{}{Swedish}\par
\lan{English}{}{}\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! Is there a way to do the same thing with three languages instead of two? In my case both Italian and Swedish should fallback to English if they are not specified.