# Converting LaTeX3 script to Lua

Tags: luatex, expl3, languages

I have a single LaTeX file from which I can output different PDFs in different languages. The system that I use right now works quite well but it is written in LaTeX3 and I found it very difficult to understand.

This is the code, the variable parts are given as “multiple arguments” to `\lc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,french,english]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% the main command
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\lc}{m} % language choice
 {
  \fabbri_lc:n { #1 }
 }
% we can change the language mid document
\NewDocumentCommand{\setlclanguage}{m}
 {
  \fabbri_lc_set:n { #1 }
 }

% variables
\str_new:N \l_fabbri_lc_lang_str
\str_new:N \l_fabbri_lc_fallback_str

% internal functions
\cs_new:Nn \fabbri_lc:n
 {
  \str_case:VnF \l_fabbri_lc_lang_str
    { #1 }
    { \str_case:Vn \l_fabbri_lc_fallback_str { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fabbri_lc_set:n
 {
  \str_set:Nn \l_fabbri_lc_lang_str { #1 }
  \fabbri_lc:n
   {
    {ita}{\selectlanguage{italian}}
    {fra}{\selectlanguage{french}}
    {eng}{\selectlanguage{english}}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fabbri_lc_set:n { e }


% setup
% set the default language based on \jobname of the form <name>-<lang>
\seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { - } \c_sys_jobname_str
\fabbri_lc_set:e { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }

% set the fallback language
\str_set:Nn \l_fabbri_lc_fallback_str { eng } % choose the fallback language

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{\lc{
  {ita}{Titolo}
  {fra}{Titre}
  {eng}{Title}
}}

\lc{
 {ita}{Questo documento è in italiano}
 {fra}{Ce document est in français}
 {eng}{This document is in English}
}

% French is missing here
\lc{
  {ita}{Testo}
  {eng}{Text}
}

% change the default language
\setlclanguage{fra}

\section{\lc{
  {ita}{Titolo}
  {fra}{Titre}
  {eng}{Title}
}}

\lc{
 {ita}{Questo documento è in italiano}
 {fra}{Ce document est in français}
 {eng}{This document is in English}
}

% French is missing here
\lc{
  {ita}{Testo}
  {eng}{Text}
}

\end{document}
```

It is possible to select the language based on the job name. The main file is named `fabbri.tex` and the PDFs are created with pdflatex with these commands:

```
pdflatex -jobname=fabbri-ita fabbri
pdflatex -jobname=fabbri-eng fabbri
```

I got the code above from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622412/multi-language-text).

I have recently updated my setup to use LuaLaTeX and I would like to:

1. Change the code above from "inline" LaTeX3 to Lua code contained in a separate file.
2. Change the language for the entire document so that the command `\today` print the date in the selected language.

Unfortunately, it seems to me that there is not much documentation on how to use Lua with LaTeX and I do not really know where to start.

Comment: Your question should be how to code this functionalities in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: You are right, the title is not the best, but I think that now it is too late to change it.

Comment: the expl3 language may look a bit daunting at the begin, but it is easier to handle than the various escaping rules and commands needed if you want to move between lua and tex. Before doing this switch better read the luacode documentation and some of the questions and answers here first. If you don't want to see the expl3 code in your preamble: simply put everything in a file `language-selection-code.sty`  and then do `\usepackage{language-selection-code}`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will read more about the integration between LaTeX and Lua. For me the main advantage of Lua is that it is used as a scripting language in a lot of different programs.
I did not know that I could move the expl3 code to a different file, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will not convert the full script for you but the following is hopefully sufficient to get you started.

To run Lua code from the LaTeX part of your document you can use the `\directlua` macro that has as argument the Lua code that you want to run. This can be a one-liner, but it can also be a call to a function that you have defined.

Defining functions can be done inside of a `luacode` environment, usually in the preamble.

To use the results of the Lua code in your document usually you add a `tex.sprint()` command in the code, which is a command that is specific for LuaLaTeX (i.e., it does not exist in regular Lua) which prints the argument in the document.

To pass an associative array to the Lua code you can use the regular Lua syntax for this kind of 'table' as it is called as the argument to `\directlua`.

Finally for `\jobname` there is a special variable `tex.jobname` available for use in the Lua code.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function llc(langmap)
   local currlang = string.sub(tex.jobname, -3)
   tex.sprint(langmap[currlang])
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand{\lc}[1]{\directlua{llc(#1)}}
\begin{document}
Jobname: \jobname

\lc{{ita="Questo documento è in italiano",
    fra="Ce document est in français",
    eng="This document is in English"}}
\end{document}
```

Result with `lualatex -jobname=fabbri-fra yourfile.tex`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very useful. Do you know how to do what I wrote in point 2?

Comment: Basically, what I need is to call `\selectlanguage{}` from within Lua.

Comment: You can use any LaTeX macro from Lua with `tex.sprint`, just make sure that you escape the backslash (for example `tex.sprint("\\selectlanguage{french}")`. You can use normal Lua string operations to construct this string by concatenating different parts, for example to get the language name from a Lua array. The basic principle is that `tex.sprint` inserts the argument in the code of the document at the current position, exactly the same as when you would have typed that code in the source yourself, including any LaTeX macros.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to write some Lua code in an external file that does everything I need!

Comment: One question, when I change the language to Swedish, I get the error `Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }` if I use `"` to delimit the strings but everything is fine if I use `'`. The problem is that sometimes I need to use the apostrophe (') in a sentence but that is not possible as Lua thinks it is used to end the string. I tried to escape the apostrophe with \ but it adds an accent to the letter after it. \\ also does not work. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try `[[some t'ext]]`?

Comment: @AlbertoFabbri indeed using the raw string syntax as suggested by projectmbc should work. The issue itself is related to Babel shorthands that redefine the meaning of ". A quick solution is to turn them off, for example `\usepackage[swedish,shorthands=off]{babel}`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Both solutions work, I opted to disable the shorthands.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use expl3 nor lua script. Your intention can be realized using only TeX primitives:

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname}
\def\trycs#1#2{\ifcsname #1\endcsname \csname #1\endcsname \else #2\fi}
\def\readlanguage #1-#2;{\def\langmark{#2}}
\def\langmark{eng} % default language
%\expandafter\readlanguage \jobname;  % read \langmark from jobname

\sdef{sel:ita}{\selectlanguage{italian}\def\lcset{1}\sdef{use:ita}{1}}
\sdef{sel:fra}{\selectlanguage{french}\def\lcset{2}\sdef{use:fra}{2}}
\sdef{sel:eng}{\selectlanguage{english}\def\lcset{3}\sdef{use:eng}{3}}

\def\lc#1{\lcA#1{}{}}
\def\lcA#1#2{%
   \ifnum\lcset=\trycs{use:#1}{0} #2\fi
   \ifx&#1&\else \expandafter\lcA \fi
}

\trycs{sel:\langmark}{} % select a language given by \langmark

% test:
\lc{
 {ita}{Questo documento è in italiano}
 {fra}{Ce document est in français}
 {eng}{This document is in English}
}
```

There is default language `eng` defined at line 4. Remove comment character from the line 5 if you want to read `\langmark` from `\jobname`, i.e. when you are using `-jobname file-fra file` at your command line.

Comment: Honestly this seems even harder to understand than expl3 and it also does not change the language for the whole document. If I use `\today` it always prints the date in English.

Comment: @AlbertoFabbri If you used `\usepackage[italian,french,english]{babel}` (as you mention in your example) then `\today` expand to the date in selected language. Moreover: you are working with TeX, so to understand the elementary TeX tools is usable (sometimes even necessary). Not all typesetting tasks can be done only by Lua. When you want to use LuaTeX at programmer level then you must understand TeX first. And when you understand TeX then my example cannot seem to you as "even harder to understand".

Comment: I understand what you said, and it makes sense, but I have already spent a lot of time trying to understand TeX and it is sometimes hard to justify it considering that all its syntax and functioning is unique and does not apply to any other program as far as I know. Anyway, I am using babel and I tried to uncomment the code that reads the language from the jobname, but it does not change the language in which ```\today``` is printed.

Comment: Furthermore, I got several warnings like this one from ChkTeX: ```You ought to not use primitive TeX in LaTeX code.```

Comment: I am not imagine what is doing in your computer. When I used `babel` then `\today` expands depending on the value of the `\langmark` macro. And I don't know what macro generates the warning about "not use primitive" but I'm interested in it. Can you be more precise?

Comment: Sure, the commands that trigger that warning are `\expandafter` and `\csname`.

Comment: Please, be more explicit. The `\expandafter` and `\csname` in my computer work normally. What you do that that the warning is printed? I am unable to imagine it.

Comment: They compile fine on my computer as well; it is just that they trigger a warning from ChkTeX (the linter) and given my not so good knowledge of LaTeX I try to do what ChkTeX advise me to do :)