# Dynamically changing document language

Tags: languages, programming

The problem may appear silly to some, but it has some applications.

For the last two years, I have been updating my CV in two languages: LANG1 and LANG2. The task has proven particularly problematic as I added new formatting, entries and additional structures to the LANG1-document but half a year later forgot what changes I did there and had to translate LANG1 into LANG2 from scratch. Other problems followed as well.

This, each entry in LaTeX should look something like

```
\def\LANG{LANG1}
\def\experienceLANG1{An amazing company}
\def\experienceLANG2{素晴らしい会社}
```

Then there should be some kind of IF-statement deciding which entries to use based on the value of `\LANG`

```
\def\experience{...decide LANG1 or LANG2 here based on the value of \LANG...}
```

And finally, the document prints the selected translation.

```
\section{\experience}
```

Is this kind of thing doable in LaTeX in a reasonable way?

Comment: Doesn’t `babel` or `translator` work for you?

Comment: Something like [this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575611/a-mode-to-produce-a-document-in-one-language-or-the-other/575613#575613)

Comment: @Davislor yes, this fully solves my problem. As this is a duplicate of the question in the link, I'll consider deleting my question.

Comment: @JantjeGöhre, I wouldn't delete your question. It's interesting and, in this case, complete enough. As you can see, two interesting solutions were proposed. There will be more people facing a similar situation.